# Could not create type 'InstantBuySample.FullHandler' error in using google wallet sample code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web, android-pay

I am getting the error Could not create type 'InstantBuySample.FullHandler'

on using the google wallet Instant Buy API. Please help me incase possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I upgraded using VS2012, the two libraries targeted .NET Framework 4 and the webapp targeted .NET Framework 2. Changing to .NET Framework 4 fixed this for me.